# Which language can be parsed recursive descent?

Tags: formal-languages, parsers, chomsky-hierarchy

We consider languages over the alphabet {a,b,c}. Given a character t in the alphabet and a non-negative integer j, by t^j we mean the string consisting of exactly j occurrences of t.

Now let m be an unknown but fixed positive integer in the following language definitions:

L1 = { a^n a^n | n <= m }

L2 = { a^n b^m | n > m }

L3 = { a^m b^n | m > n }

L4 = { a^n b^n c^n | n <= m }

L5 = { p^n q^n r^n | n >= m }

For each of the languages L1, L2, L3, L4, and L5, state whether it can be parsed using recursive decents.

I have concluded that only L1 can be parsed using recursive descent, is this correct or not?
How should I really think about this question?

Comment: @YvesDaoust thanks have fixed it now